# Location.Reload() breaking my jquery flow

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to uncheck my checkboxes after a `location.reload()` event in Jquery. The unchecking method works if the `location.reload()` is not present. But when I add `location.reload()`, the unchecking step does not work.

```
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' class='c1' name='me' checked />
    <input type='checkbox' class='c1' name='me' checked />
    <input type='checkbox' class='c1' name='me' checked />
    <input type='checkbox' class='c1' name='me' checked />
    <button id='btn'>SUBMIT</button>
</div>
<script>
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        
        location.reload();
        $('.c1').attr('checked', false);

    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: On location.reload your page is getting reloaded to the default state... Why do you want location.reload ?

Comment: In my actual code, i want to refresh the page after an ajax call and then restore some checkboxes to their original state .. that is why i am using location.reload to refresh the page and then restore the checkboxes

Comment: After the page has reloaded, the function is no longer active. You must again click the button to call it, which makes you go round in circles.

Comment: ok. then i will have to find an alternative to location.reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location.reload` will refresh the page and your checkboxes will appear in default state(In this case `checked`)

One thing you can do, is use of `sessionStorage`. Store checkbox state before reloading the page and after document gets successfully loaded check the state of checkboxes.

Like

```js
   
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if (sessionStorage.getItem('checkboxState')) {
                $('.c1').attr('checked', Boolean(sessionStorage.getItem('checkboxState')));
            }
        })
        $('#btn').click(function(){
            sessionStorage.setItem('checkboxState',  !$('.c1').attr('checked'))
            location.reload();
    
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <input type='checkbox' class='c1' name='me' checked />
        <input type='checkbox' class='c1' name='me' checked />
        <input type='checkbox' class='c1' name='me' checked />
        <input type='checkbox' class='c1' name='me' checked />
        <button id='btn'>SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
```